# LibreOffice Calc - How can I create a custom legend?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'd like to use a custom legend for a diagram. Is that possible?

If it's helpful for anyone:

- Xubuntu 13.10
- LO 4.1

Comment: How should the legend look like?

Comment: Prett much like the standard one, except that I would like to have customs descriptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can create a custom legend. To do so, **you will have to provide the custom Data Range names separately in your spreadsheet** (you can use the same sheet as our data, a separate sheet or even a separate `.ods` file). This is because the "data range name" is used in the legend by default; and the data range name is always set using a cell range reference.

With the custom data range names prepared, you can reference them in the third step of the "`Insert Chart`" wizard (Menu "`Insert`" -> "`Chart...`"). In the following screenshot, i'm creating a chart from values `B2:B4`, using the content of `A24` as name:

[image]

You can also add or edit the legend later. To do so:

- Double-Click on the chart to open "`Chart edit`" mode (or right-click on the chart and select "`Edit`");
- right-click on the chart to open the context menu and select "`Data Ranges`", or
- Menu "`Format`" -> "`Data Ranges`".

This will show the following dialogue, the same as the third wizard step:

[image]

The "`Data series`" list box shows the data series name as it will appear in the legend.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the symbol " in the begining and the end of the legend title.|

e.g

Range for Name : " My Custom Tilte 34 "